# 'infopath cannot submit the form because it contains errors' when using External Item Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, bcs, sharepoint2010-bcs

I get 'infopath cannot submit the form because it contains errors' when trying to create new item in External List. The External Content Type this list is built on has a reference to another External Content Type.

The external types are Phase and Project. Phase referencing a Project using ProjectID field. On the InfoPath form generated for 'New Item' action for Phases list there is a External Item Picker. If I replace this control with a simple text box for the ProjectID - problem disappear. But I need to use 'External Item Picker'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help solving your problem. Check the ULS Logs for what might be the cause of the error.

Comment: I wonder if it can help me cause it's a client (not server) error. JavaScript validation is failed. But anyway I will check these logs.